# DB2 trigger timing out

Tags: sql, triggers, db2

I have the following trigger which ensures only one record has the field DEFAULTCARD=1

```
create trigger TRG_U_XSTRDCRD
     after update on XSTOREDCARD referencing new as N old as O
     for each row mode db2sql
     begin atomic
        if N.DEFAULTCARD = 1 then
            update XSTOREDCARD
                set DEFAULTCARD = 0
                where USERS_ID = N.USERS_ID and ID <> N.ID;
        end if;
     end@
```

I would also like to make sure that only one record has the EBACTIVE field value of 1, so i tried this.

```
create trigger TRG_U_XSTRDCRD
     after update on XSTOREDCARD referencing new as N old as O
     for each row mode db2sql
     begin atomic
        if N.DEFAULTCARD = 1 then
            update XSTOREDCARD
                set DEFAULTCARD = 0
                where USERS_ID = N.USERS_ID and ID <> N.ID;
        end if;
        if N.EBACTIVE = 1 then
            update XSTOREDCARD
                set EBACTIVE = 0
                where USERS_ID = N.USERS_ID and ID <> N.ID;
        end if;
     end@
```

But it did not work, it results on a timeout after a few minutes on update:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -101, SQLSTATE: 54001, SQLERRMC: null
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.zc.e(zc.java:1606)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.zc.a(zc.java:1206)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.db.h(db.java:149)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.db.a(db.java:43)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.r.a(r.java:30)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.sb.g(sb.java:152)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.zc.n(zc.java:1186)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.db(ad.java:1761)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.d(ad.java:2203)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.V(ad.java:521)
at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ad.executeUpdate(ad.java:504)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2595)
... 19 more
```

Any advice on whats wrong or how to do it?

Cheers!
NFV

Comment: Please show the exact error code and the complete message.

Comment: SQLCODE -101 is not a timeout; it means you are hitting a memory limit or some other resource limit. Since you haven't mentioned you DB2 version and platform, I can't give you more details. Talk to your DBA.

Comment: The following page might have some hints for you. http://www.dbforums.com/db2/978746-sql0954c-not-enough-storage-available-application-heap-process.html

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this nice post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.databases.ibm-db2/mR8DDSXusLg), it might have dawned on me that you do a few updates to many. You defined a post update trigger, which updates the same table. You actually update all rows for that one user. so let's say you have 10 rows per user and one row changed the DEFAULTCARD flag. That means you update 9 rows regardless whether they needed to be updated. That doesn't sound to be a big deal, however, if you have 5,000,000 records, then you update 4,999,999 records even though you only needed to update one (namely the old DEFAULTCARD record).

```
        update XSTOREDCARD
            set DEFAULTCARD = 0
            where USERS_ID = N.USERS_ID and DEFAULTCARD = 1 and ID <> N.ID;
```

This statement should only effect 1 or no record. So instead of running 4,999,999 updates and trigger calls you only have one update.

The same is true for EBACTIVE. Even better, if the EBACTIVE and the DEFAULTCARD are 1 for different record, it will get really messy, since an update To EBACTIVE will Trigger an Update to DEFAULTCARD which will trigger an update to EBACTIVE again. So if I am not mistaken, you are in an infinite loop.

```
 begin atomic
    if N.DEFAULTCARD = 1 then
        update XSTOREDCARD
            set DEFAULTCARD = 0
            where USERS_ID = N.USERS_ID and DEFAULTCARD = 1 and ID <> N.ID;
    end if;
    if N.EBACTIVE = 1 then
        update XSTOREDCARD
            set EBACTIVE = 0
            where USERS_ID = N.USERS_ID and EBACTIVE = 1 and ID <> N.ID;
    end if;
 end@
```

This should perform way better.

**EDIT:** second try

My be we should only update a dataset, if the value actually changed.

```
 begin atomic
    if N.DEFAULTCARD = 1 and O.DEFAULTCARD != 1 then
        update XSTOREDCARD
            set DEFAULTCARD = 0
            where USERS_ID = N.USERS_ID and DEFAULTCARD = 1 and ID <> N.ID;
    end if;
    if N.EBACTIVE = 1 and O.EBACTIVE !=1 then
        update XSTOREDCARD
            set EBACTIVE = 0
            where USERS_ID = N.USERS_ID and EBACTIVE = 1 and ID <> N.ID;
    end if;
 end@
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion it looked like a good one but I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: How big is your table?

Comment: try my edit then, you most likely have an endless loop in your trigger